# How to read error lines & detect origin of error in "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" Warning

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, constraints

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.

Try this:

1. Look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
2. Find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.

**Please tell me how to read these lines of error/warnings, I mean how can I detect the origin of problem**

```
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009e370 UIView:0x7fdc38d1ac50.height == 1   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009e410 UILabel:0x7fdc38d1adf0'1 hour ago'.height == 20   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009d880 UIButton:0x7fdc38e39b80.height == 25   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009dc90 UICollectionView:0x7fdc39832600.height == 120   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009e6e0 V:|-(16)-[UILabel:0x7fdc38e39f70'RFA(DEB/TACE) recommended']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fdc38d1a8c0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009e820 V:[UILabel:0x7fdc38e39f70'RFA(DEB/TACE) recommended']-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fdc3ba068b0'Asking for Self, Female, ...']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009e910 V:[UILabel:0x7fdc3ba068b0'Asking for Self, Female, ...']-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fdc3ba18770'kindly help me doctor rec...']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009e960 V:[UILabel:0x7fdc3ba18770'kindly help me doctor rec...']-(16)-[UICollectionView:0x7fdc39832600]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009eaf0 V:[UICollectionView:0x7fdc39832600]-(16)-[UILabel:0x7fdc38d1adf0'1 hour ago']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009eb90 V:[UILabel:0x7fdc38d1adf0'1 hour ago']-(8)-[UIView:0x7fdc38d1ac50]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009ecd0 V:[UIButton:0x7fdc38e39b80]-(16)-[UIButton:0x7fdc3ba184a0'Post Answer']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009ed20 V:[UIButton:0x7fdc3ba184a0'Post Answer']-(16)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fdc38d1a8c0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009ee10 V:[UIView:0x7fdc38d1ac50]-(8)-[UIButton:0x7fdc38e39b80]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009ef50 V:|-(8)-[UIView:0x7fdc38d1a8c0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdc38d1a6f0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009efa0 V:[UIView:0x7fdc38d1a8c0]-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdc38d1a6f0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009f900 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fdc38d1a6f0.height == 170   (active)>"
```

)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Comment: You probably having more than needed constraint than it needs to works, the easiest way to figure this is simply change the device in the storyboard, which might show red if the constraint cant be satisfy

Comment: See http://staxmanade.com/2015/06/debugging-ios-autolayout-issues/

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.wtfautolayout.com

Comment: Please post the line after the `Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint`, thats most important.